# Is there custom components in Objective-C like Java?

Tags: java, objective-c, swing, components

In java, I know you can extend JComponent and override paintComponent(Graphics), like below:

```
public class MyComp extends JComponent {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 5, 5);
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there was a way to do something similar to this in Objective-C.

Comment: There's not a whole lot of reason to with Objective-C if you're writing apps; most of the time in Objective-C you'll be drawing objects or making them hidden/unhidden by calling a method on the object; there really isn't much need for overwriting something like a "paintComponent" method.

Comment: Additionally, if you're making a game, I would advise using SpriteKit, which does a lot of things automatically, like updating graphics every frame and having a lot of pre-packaged goodies like the Physics bundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a class that extends from `UIView` and override it's `drawRect` method, which will allow to perform custom painting, but then you're getting to the Core Graphics layer

You can also use `CALayer`, but I'm less familiar with this and have only used in when adding content to a `UIView`, but as I understand it, it has some inbuilt animation capabilities.

You could have a look at

- [Custom Control for iOS Tutorial: A Reusable Knob](http://www.raywenderlich.com/56885/custom-control-for-ios-tutorial-a-reusable-knob)
- [How To Make a Custom Control](http://www.raywenderlich.com/36288/how-to-make-a-custom-control)

As some examples...